# How to determine with what probability it is possible to guarantee that the absolute error allowed in this case will not exceed some $\varepsilon $

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

How to determine the quality of the products produced by the plant, 2500 products were selected at random. Among them there were 50 with defects. The frequency of manufacturing defective products is taken as an approximate value of the probability of manufacturing a defective product. Determine with what probability it is possible to guarantee that the absolute error allowed in this case will not exceed 0.02.

I tried to use Bernulli theorem :
$P(| \frac{m}{n} - p | < \varepsilon ) \approx 2 \Phi ( \frac{\sqrt{n}*\varepsilon}{\sqrt{pq}} )$

here $\Phi$ is a gaussian function.
After calcualtion i have a 1. Correct answer is 0.98, how can i get it?

Comment: How did you get $1$?

Comment: $\Phi(50*0.02/ \sqrt{0.02*0.98}) = \Phi(7.14) = 0.5$ .for finding value of function i use a table from my textbook (Ryabushko chapter 4)

Comment: The last equality is hard to believe: the RHS must be irrational. The first equality must be wrong too for the same reason.

Comment: I don't know any others ways to solve this

Comment: What are the mean and standard deviation of your $\Phi$? What is the formula of $\Phi$ that you used?

Comment: @markvs $\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2*\pi}}*  \int_{0}^{x} e^{-z^2/2} \,dz $

Comment: So the mean is $0$ and deviation is $1$? Why?

Comment: It is noraml distribution formula after standartisation. z = (x - mean)/std. in russian textbooks it is using for easy calculation

Comment: 1. I am sure you use a wrong formula (the mean cannot be $0$ for your problem. 2. You round up numbers incorrectly. The integral from $0$ to $7.14$ cannot be $.5$.

Comment: Look at it: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_2_3_normal.php#:~:text=The%20CDF%20of%20the%20standard%20normal%20distribution%20is%20denoted%20by,is%20widely%20used%20in%20probability.

Comment: @markvs Note that he's centering the estimate, so using mean $0$ makes sense.  Also, while the integral from $0$ to $7.14$ isn't exactly $.5$, that's probably accurate to about $20$ decimal places, so it's probably not where the mistake lies...

Comment: @user6247850; why center at 0, what is the deviation.

Comment: @markvs It looks like rrryok is attempting to use the central limit theorem (although possibly without understanding it super well), so $\frac{p(1-p)}{\sqrt{n}}$ would be the standard deviation.

Comment: @user6247850: So he does integrate a wrong function?

Comment: @markvs There's a standard result to convert the CDF of a normal with variance $\sigma^2$ (say $\hat \Phi$) to the CDF of a standard normal $\Phi$, specifically $\hat \Phi(x) = \Phi(x/\sigma)$.